# accessing elements in a list in javascript html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list - `[getFamilyPkg, getActivePkg, getEligiblePkg, getActivePkgForDeactivation]`,  want to get each element in this list in a javascript function. 
How to do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Assume list is stored in a variable called `arr`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var elem = arr[i];
  // elem is either getFamilyPkg, or getActivePkg, or ...
}
```

Comment: for (var i=0;i<3;i++)
{ 
         webService_list.remove(0);   }   Why this won't work?

Comment: There is no `remove` method on JS arrays. Use `pop` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Tommy's answer is actually incorrect. `for (var i in arr)` loops over all attributes/properties of the `arr` object prototype, which includes builtin functions like `slice()`, etc. See jsfiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/sEtMw/ (check the console and you will see a bunch of extra properties other than the array elements.

There are a few approaches (once again assuming the array is named `arr`):

```
var elem;
for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
    elem = arr[i];
    // elem is actually one of the array elements here
}
```

Another option is as follows:

```
var elem;
while (elem = arr.shift()) {
    // elem is one of the array elements
}
```

Please note that the second approach does **not** keep the array intact. i.e. at the end of the loop, the array will be empty. But if you are okay with that, the syntax is definitely cleaner. Both approaches are illustrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/z7zKK/. The variable `arr` is logged at the end to illustrate that it is empty.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Let me edit my answer to use a simple i = 0...i++ approach. You get a big upvote from me!

Comment: In your defense, I think the fact that javascript lacks a foreach loop is a terrible terrible flaw!

Comment: Yea, it's pretty bad. Luckily underscore.js comes with a `_.each(...)`!

Comment: Yeah, and jQuery as well, but while I cannot speak for `_.each` efficiency, `jQuery.each` is roughly 20 times slower than a `for` loop in similar situations. I have no clue how they wrote it to be so slow. Potentially jQuery object creation overhead?